# Calling virtual method from a constructor

Tags: java, java-8

Java 8

I was just a little perplexed by that we could not call virtual method from a constructor. The pitfall is that we can overload it and crash. But what if we call it from within a constructor of a ***final*** class. Like this:

```
public final class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private final Object[] arr;
    public MyClass(){
        Object[] arr;
        //init arr
        this.arr = arr;
        //Now we have to preprocess it
        preprocess();
    }

    @Override
    public void preprocess(){
        //impl
    }

    public int count(){
        //impl
    }
}

public interface MyInterface{
    void preprocess();
    int count();
}
```

Are there other pitfalls with calling virtual methods from within a constructor? Of course, I can extract preprocess into a static method and then call it from both, but it looks a little messy. I'd like to keep code as clean as possible.

Comment: How is a final class a pitfall? That just means you can't extend that class... You still need to implement the interfaces methods, so calling them in the constructor has nothing to do with the class being final

Comment: @cricket_007 No, it seems you don't understand. J. Bloch in his effective Java wrote that we shouldn't call non-final method from a constructor. As that if we do, we'll run the risk of introducing a bug.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, fixed.

Comment: @cricket_007 Well, can you just tell me if it's safe or not :)?

Comment: I didn't read that book, so I'm not sure what kinds of bugs that would be.

Comment: "I was just a little perplexed by that we could not call virtual method from a constructor." But you can. It's just not a good idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, In case of non-final classes it's actually not a good one. But what's wrong with calling them from a constructor of a final class?

Comment: That's fine. I'm disputing the first asertion in your question, namely that you *could not* call a virtual method. If you meant that you'd read that you *should not* I suggest you change the question, because those mean very different things.

Comment: When you call a method from a constructor and somebody subclasses you so that you call the method on the subclass (which is only possible if not final) then the subclass will work with a incomlete initialized class (as the initialisation is only finished after the constructor is exited). In your case it does not make a difference if the method belongs to an interface or not, the only question is if a subclass can override it.

Comment: Use common sense. Since you know for sure that the object under construction is of your class exactly, then you know for sure that you control the override that will be called. So there is no harm that could be caused *by external code* in this case.

Comment: Constructors are responsible for initializing objects with their invariants established.  Exposing a partially constructed object -- even to _friendly_ code (e.g., final method of the same class) -- is risky.  Exposing a partially constructed object to _alien_ code (code outside your class, or overrideable methods), is downright dangerous. (Among other risks, publishing an object before construction is complete undermines the final-field safety guaranteed by the JMM.)  Also, doing so is very rarely necessary -- better to suffer a little repetition than to bury timebombs in your code.

Comment: @user3663882 When coding a method for your class, do you really want to be always thinking "this method might get invoked on a not-completely-initialized instance -- I can't count on fields having correct or consistent values", and coding suitably defensively for every method that might be called from the ctor?  Do you really want to impose that on your maintainers?

Comment: @Brian Goetz: the question is where to draw the line regarding the “little repetition”…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always take care when calling methods from a constructor, because the object construction is not yet complete. This is true even for `final` and `private` methods, which cannot be overridden by subclasses.

Example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sub().test();
    }
}
class Base {
    int b;
    Base() {
        test();
        this.b = 1;
    }
    void test() {
        System.out.println("Hello from Base. b = " + this.b);
    }
}
class Sub extends Base {
    int s;
    Sub() {
        test();
        this.s = 2;
    }
    @Override
    void test() {
        System.out.println("Hello from Sub. b = " + this.b + ", s = " + this.s);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hello from Sub. b = 0, s = 0
Hello from Sub. b = 1, s = 0
Hello from Sub. b = 1, s = 2
```

`test()` is called 3 times: From `Base` constructor, from `Sub` constructor, and from `main()`.

As you can see, even field `b` was not yet initialized on the first call.

So, is it illegal to do it? No.
Should you avoid it? Yes.
Just make it clear (e.g. javadoc) that the method may be called on partially initialized objects.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify it once more. We can call virtual methods from the constructor. But even for final classes it is fragile and great care must be taken when doing so, right?

Comment: @user3663882 Correct.

Comment: There are two problems with this answer. First, it presents an example that's not what the OP is asking, because the OP is asking about *final classes specifically*. Second, it misses the point of the guideline that the OP is asking about, which is the fact that *external code* may start using a partially constructed instance. But, in the case of final methods, this isn't a problem, unless the OP makes the mistake of calling *actually overridable* code elsewhere.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis You are right my example went further than question context, but my point is still valid. Also, how am I missing the point of *external code* using partially constructed instance, when my example shows the pitfall of exactly that? Which is why I extended the answer, to clarify what the pitfall is.

Comment: @Andreas You demonstrated exactly the pitfall that external code may use a partially constructed instance, but you did so by sidestepping the premise of the question, which was that the class is final. If you had made your class final, as the question stated, then the called method in your example would not be external to the class in any way. The problem (if any) would occur in code internal to the class, making the guideline irrelevant, since that guideline is about *external code* messing up (by not respecting or knowing the initialization procedure of your class).